# Get "top level" edge based on vertex name in DAG

Tags: r, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs

```
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Tom", "Cecil", "Alice", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Cecil", "Esmeralda", "Esmeralda", "David"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE)
plot(g)
```

I can find the parent of a vertex like this:

```
head_of(g, E(g)[V(g)[name=="Bob"]])
```

My question is: how can I find the top level parent of a vertex? In this case following the path

Bob -> Alice -> Esmeralda -> David

I have the vertex name Bob as input and want to find the top level parent (David).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the subgraph of points that you can reach from "Bob" (using only out-bound links), then the top level parent that you seek will be the most distant point from "Bob".

```
SUB = induced_subgraph(g, subcomponent(g, "Bob", mode="out"))
TopLevel = farthest.nodes(SUB)$vertices[2]
TopLevel
+ 1/4 vertex, named:
[1] David
```

Comment: Great! Any idea how I can get just the vertex name as a string/character?

Comment: If you just want the string and not the whole node, you can use `TopLevel$name`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, by you could always walk the outgoing neighbors till there are no more. For example

```
top_node <- function(v) {
  vx <- V(g)[v]
  vresut <- vx
  visited <- c()
  while(length(vx)>0 && !(vx %in% visited)) {
    if (length(vx)>1) stop("multiple outgoing nodes found")
    vresult <- vx
    visited <- c(visited, vx)
    vx <- V(g)[outnei(vx)]  
  }
  vresult
}

top_node("Bob")
```

This assumes that each node has one outgoing node and that there are no loops/circuits.